# LetA,B∈R. Prove by epsilon − N definition that if ak converges and bk converges, then Abk−Bak+ 1 converges.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-writing

I am not sure how to prove this using the epsilon-delta proof for a converging sequence. Please note the ks are subscripted

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $a_k\rightarrow L_1$ and $b_k\rightarrow L_2,$ so there are some natural numbers $N_1,N_2\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $$k\geq N_1\implies|a_k-L_1|<\epsilon {\text{ and }} k\geq N_2\implies|b_k-L_2|<\epsilon.$$

If these are the points to which $(a_k)_{k=1}^\infty$ and $(b_k)_{k=1}^\infty$ converge, make an appropriate guess for the point $L$ to which the sequence $(Ab_k-Ba_k+1)_{k=1}^\infty$ would converge. Then check that $|Ab_k-Ba_k+1-L|<\epsilon$ for "big enough" $k.$ It should take just some simple factoring and the triangle inequality.